# How can I separate generated artifacts from the main build with semantic UI?

Tags: npm, gulp, semantic-ui

I am trying to figure out how to integrate Semantic UI with my gulp-based frontend toolchain.

The npm artifact `semantic-ui` includes an interactive installer that will write a `semantic.json` file to the root of my project and install the less files, gulp tasks and some configuration into my project. All of these files will be put in subdirectories of a single base directory specified in semantic.json.

I do not want any dependency implementation files or any generated files in the git repository for my project because this will pollute revision history and lead to unneccessary merge conflicts. I would very much prefer to provide `semantic.json` only and `.gitignore` the semantic base directory. On `npm install`, the Semantic installer should install everything to the base directory specified in `semantic.json`. When building, I want the artifacts generated into a separate dist directory that does not reside under the semantic base directory.

However, if I do this, the installer will fail with a message stating that it cannot find the directories to update and drop me into the interactive installer instead. This is not what I want, because it means my build is no longer non-interactive (which will cause the CI build to fail).

How can I integrate Semantic UI into my build without having to commit Semantic and its generated artifacts into my git repository?

Comment: If you haven't modified Semantic UI in any way (i.e. added themes or changes variables/overrides) and are just downloading it and building, why do you want to use its build system anyway? Why not just use the build from Bower?

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, but there will be a need for theming in the future. So the question is still valid.

Answer (score 14):

This is what we did in our similar scenario. The following are true:

- Everything Semantic UI generates is in *.gitignore*. Therefore, the only Semantic UI files we have in our repo are:

  - *semantic.json*
  - *semantic/src* folder (this is where our theme modifications actually are)
  - *semantic/tasks* folder (probably doesn't need to be on git, but since it's needed for building, everything is simpler if we keep it in our repo)
- We never need to (re)run the Semantic UI installer, everything is integrated in our own *gulpfile.js*.
- Semantic UI outputs in our *assets* folder which is not in the same folder as its sources.
- Semantic UI is updated automatically using npm as per the rules in my *package.json*.

Here are the steps needed to achieve this:

1. Install Semantic UI. By this I assume that you either used npm or cloned it from git (using npm is **highly** recommended), either way, you have *semantic.json* in your project's main folder and a *semantic* folder with *gulpfile.js*, *src* and *tasks*.
2. Make sure Semantic UI can be built. Navigate to *semantic/* and run `gulp build`. This should create a *dist* folder in your *semantic/* directory. Delete it and also delete Semantic UI's *gulpfile.js* since you'll no longer need it.
3. Edit *semantic.json*. You need to edit two lines:

   1. Change `"packaged": "dist/",` to the path where you'd like to output *semantic.css* and *semantic.js* relative to Semantic UI's folder. In our case, it was `"packaged": "../../assets/semantic/",`
   2. Change `"themes": "dist/themes/"` in the same way, since the *themes/* folder contains fonts and images Semantic UI uses so it needs to be in the same folder as *semantic.css*. In our case, it was `"themes": "../../assets/semantic/dist/themes/"`.
4. Edit your *gulpfile.js* so that it uses Semantic UI's build task. Add `var semanticBuild = require('./semantic/tasks/build');` (if *semantic/* is in the same folder as your *gulpfile.js*) and then simply register a task that depends on it, for example `gulp.task('semantic', semanticBuild);`.
5. Optionally, create a *clean* task. We used [del](https://www.npmjs.com/package/del) for that.

   ```
   gulp.task('clean:semantic', function(cb) {
       del(['assets/semantic'], cb);
   });
   ```

Comment: Looks promising, thanks! However, are you certain that tasks that depend on your `semantic` task only get started after your `semantic` task completes? Because the gulp scripts for semantic use `gulp.start()`, which means gulp has no way of knowing when the build has completed.

Comment: I'm not - we keep semantic as a separate task because it takes a long time to build and we therefore only do it when we need to. You could perhaps use [gulp-chug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-chug) to achieve what you want and actually invoke Semantic UI's gulpfile.js, but I'm not certain about this.