# Semantic UI in .gitignore

Tags: git, semantic-ui

I recently started experimenting with Semantic UI. I am using it in a project that I keep in git repo.

I added the Semantic files to the *semantic* folder in the project root with all the default settings. I may or may not change these settings later.

My question is, how do I properly add the folder to git? I do not want to add files that can later be simply rebuilt using `gulp`, if that is possible. What files should I add and what should I ignore?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792758/how-can-i-separate-generated-artifacts-from-the-main-build-with-semantic-ui

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up partially following @fstanis's answer at [How can I separate generated artifacts from the main build with semantic UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31792758), linked by @poke.

**I kept**:

- *semantic.json*
- *semantic/src/*
- *semantic/gulpfile.js* (As I do not use `gulp` elsewhere in the project)

**I ignored**:

- *semantic/dist/*
- *semantic/tasks/*, as it is exactly the same as *node_modules/semantic-ui/tasks* and therefore can be copied

I also augmented *semantic/gulpfile.js* as follows to check if *semantic/tasks* is present and copy it there if not.

```js
/* Very top of semantic/gulpfile.js */
var fs = require('fs-extra'); // Used for recursive copying
var path = require('path');
try {
    var stat = fs.statSync(path.join(__dirname, './tasks'));
    console.log('\'tasks\' folder already exists. Continuing.')
} catch (e) {
    console.log('Copying \'tasks\' folder from \'node_modules/semantic-ui/tasks\'');
    fs.copySync(path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules/semantic-ui/tasks'), path.join(__dirname, './tasks'));
    console.log('Copying done! Continuing.');
}
```

This seems to be the minimum needed for a buildable Semantic UI installation.

Comment: @ahoff Follow the code in your answer, and after that what should I do?
call `gulp build` or call `yarn install` or `npm install`?

Comment: @NattaWang It's been a while since I posted this and I haven't used Semantic UI or Node.js since. I have a hunch for `gulp build` but I can't really tell any more.

Comment: @NattaWang you can change into semantic's directory and `gulp build` or alternatively add a script to your `package.json` that builds semantic for you (`"build:styles": "npx gulp --gulpfile [path to semantic's folder]\gulpfile.js build`)

Answer (score 5):

With reference to your own answer, I have a similar but slightly different approach that may require an additional hacky little step but keeps the repo a lot cleaner.

My `.gitignore` looks like this:

```
node_modules
semantic/dist/*
semantic/gulpfile.js
semantic/src/definitions
semantic/src/semantic.less
semantic/src/theme.less
semantic/src/themes
semantic/tasks
!semantic/dist/semantic.min.css
!semantic/dist/semantic.min.js
```

So, the main thing that's different from your solution is that I additionally ignored files inside the `src/` directory, like the definitions and all those themes.

**But**: You have to do the Semantic setup after cloning the repo. **And**: That may overwrite your `semantic.json` so you will need to revert that change – the hacky step I mentioned earlier.

Those two dist files are included for cases when Semantic just is to be used, without the need of changing anything.

Comment: The overwriting of `semantic.json` hasn't so far occurred to me with Semantic UI v4.12.2.